# How to merge hyphenated words with regex in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have numerous OCR-ed texts with hyphenated words in the middle of lines.

**Example:**
This is a text with a `hyphen- ated` word in the middle of the sentence. But it also has `- dashes -` like the ones in the second sentence. The latter should not be modified.

I would like to have a cleaned text like the one below where the hyphenated words are merged:

> This is a text with a hyphenated word in the middle. But it also has -
> dashes - like the ones in the second sentence. The latter should not
> be modified.

By removing the hyphen, this `-\s*\r?\n\s*\r?\n?` regex merges the hyphenated words if the hyphen is located at the end of the lines. How to modify this regex to do the above job? The number of spaces after the hyphen can be 1, 2 or 3 like `hyphen- ated`, `hyphen-  ated`, `hyphen-   ated`.

Answer (score 2):

You can look for a non-space (the end of a word) followed by `-`:

```regex
([^\s\d])(-\s+)
```

Then simply replace with `$1` to leave the last character of the word intact.

Here is a working example on regex101.com:
https://regex101.com/r/Zl7lvR/1

Comment: Many thanks for your swift response! While cleaning the Hungarian texts with your suggested regex, I realized that they also remove the hyphens when they should be preserved. Examples: 1. 2001-ben (in 2001). Hyphen should not be removed if it is preceded by a number. 2.  8-10. Hyphen should not be removed when it connects two numbers. 3. Szükséges-e (Is it needed) Hypen should not be deleted if it is followed by the letter e and space(s). I wonder if you could modify any of the above to take these exceptions into consideration. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then please provide a better text for testing all the rules in your original post.

Comment: In either case I have updated the answer by adding `\d` to the excluded characters and changed `\s*` to `\s+` to force at least one empty space before the next word.

Comment: I wonder if you could help me refine the ([^\s\d])(-\s+) regex: 1. it should only join hyphenated words if the letter after the hyphen is a lowercase letter = the second part of the divided word canNOT start with an upper case letter, punctuation mark, brackets or number. 2. It should NOT unite hyphenated words where the second part of the divided word is either "és " (and) or "tér " (square).
I'd like to use the regex in both Notepad++ and Python. In the application using Python I can have only a one-line regex (separated by comma) such as ([^\s\d])(-\s+),\1

Comment: Mmh I see, that's a little harder to do. You should ask a new question for that so that more people can see it. Don't know if I have the time.

Comment: Example - the following text should remain unchanged after applying the modified regex. 

     Nyugat- Németország kormánya
     Text text text Kelet-
     Európa
     Text text text Valéria-
     tér sarok.
     érettségi után a Színház- és 
     Filmművészeti Főiskolára járt
     text text text elválaszt-
     (this is due to OCR errors)
     2001-ben
     8-10
     Szükséges-e

Comment: Thanks, Peter, for the swift response and the suggestion. You were right . This was more complicated. The solution is: ([^\W\d_])-\s+(?=(?!(?:és|tér)\b)[a-zàâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœ])

Answer (score 2):

Using notepad++ you can use thia pattern and replace with an empty string:

```
[^\s-]\K-\s{1,3}
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^\s-]` Match a single char other than - or a whitespace char
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `-\s{1,3}` Match `-` and 1-3 whitespace chars to be removed

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9y3PW4/1)

Another variant matching 1+ whitespace chars and asserting a single char other than `-` or a whitespace char to the right

```
[^\s-]\K-\s+(?=[^\s-])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kmXcmf/1)

Or with the 1-3 quantifier and the lookahead:

```
[^\s-]\K-\s{1,3}(?=[^\s-])
```

Comment: @learner2021 For the examples in the other comment, none of the hyphens are deleted, see https://regex101.com/r/nhQ8R5/1

Comment: Examples: 1. 2001-ben (in 2001). Hyphen should not be removed if it is preceded by a number. 2. 8-10. Hyphen should not be removed when it connects two numbers. 3. Szükséges-e (Is it needed) Hypen should not be deleted if it is followed by the letter e and space(s). I wonder if you could modify any of the above to take these exceptions into consideration. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @learner2021 the patterns jn the answer match what is expected right? Is there an example not correct that is missed perhaps?